# IPtables how change to firewalld by MASQUERADE?

Tags: iptables, centos7, firewalld

How use firewalld-cmd use iptables rule?

iptables:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Answer (score 1):

firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 filter POSTROUTING 0 -t nat -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

POSTROUTING 0 means high priority
whthout --permanent it just works before reboot

Answer (score 0):

The Varint's command after the firewalld reload will cause a syntax issue. This command worked for me: `firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-rule ipv4 nat POSTROUTING 0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`

Comment: The question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow as defined in the [help]. Please don't answer such questions; instead, you should flag them for attention and they will be closed or migrated appropriately.